# Problemas ao usar $state.go do angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
.controller('cadastroCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$http', function ($scope, $stateParams, $http, $cordovaSQLite, $window, $state) {

$scope.emailCli = [];
$scope.emailPro = [];

$scope.cadastrar = function(usuario){

    $http.post("http://ec2-54-68-29-61.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/auth/register", usuario).success(function(response){

        var name = response.user.name;
        var email = response.user.email;
        var id = response.user.id;
        var is_professional = response.user.is_professional;    

        if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined"){    

            if(is_professional == true){
                localStorage.setItem('userPro', name);
                $scope.emailPro = localStorage.setItem('emailPro', email);
                localStorage.setItem('idPro', id);

                console.log('Professional');

                $state.go('menuProfissional');
            }else{
                localStorage.setItem('userCli', name);
                $scope.emailCli = localStorage.setItem('emailCli', email);
                localStorage.setItem('idCli', id);

                console.log('Client');

                $state.go('menuCliente');
            }
        }else{
            console.log("Desculpe, mas o navegador nao possui suporte a Web Storage.");
        }

    })
}

}])
```

E no route.js

```
.state('menuCliente', {
    url: '/menuCliente',
    templateUrl: 'templates/menuCliente.html',
    controller: 'menuClienteCtrl'
  })
```

.state('menuProfissional', {
        url: '/menuProfissional',
        templateUrl: 'templates/menuProfissional.html',
        controller: 'menuProfissionalCtrl'
      })

E o seguinte aviso de erro aparece no console:

> Cannot read property 'go' of undefined

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sua inicialização do controle está incompleta, e por causa disso a referência a `$state` está com o valor `NULL`.

Você está utilizando o formato de declaração de *providers* em *array*, entretanto apenas 3 dos 6 da interface da função estão sendo declarados.

Onde se lê:

```
.controller('cadastroCtrl', 
['$scope', '$stateParams', '$http', 
function ($scope, $stateParams, $http, $cordovaSQLite, $window, $state) {
```

Modifique para:

```
.controller('cadastroCtrl', 
['$scope', '$stateParams', '$http', '$cordovaSQLite', '$window', '$state',
function ($scope, $stateParams, $http, $cordovaSQLite, $window, $state) {
```

Comment: Valeu cara, era isso mesmo.

Comment: +1 Deveria ser a resposta aceita.

Comment: @GustavoSevero fico feliz que tenha funcionado!